# Serialize calls in $q.all

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Requirements have changed and I'm in a position where I can either completely refactor a boatload of code, or figure out how to serialize a number of functions in a `$q.all` promise.

```
var serverCalls = [];

_.each(items, function(item) {
    serverCalls.push(processItem(item));
});

return $q.all(serverCalls);
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to call the functions in `$q.all` in sequence instead of in parallel without having to massively refactor the code that puts it all together.

Comment: Sure. make serverCalls a promise, then chain with .then inside the each. return serverCalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are needing to run them in sequence, you need to make sure that you stack up an array of all of the results so that the outside world still gets the array of results that would normally have been returned from `$q.all`:

```
var serverCalls = Promise.resolve();
var results = [];

_.each(items, function(item) {
    // remember, .then() returns a new promise
    serverCalls = serverCalls.then(function() {
        return processItem(item).then(function(result) {
            results.push(result)
        });
    });
});

return serverCalls.then(function () {
    return results;
});
```

### Explanation

It's difficult to explain what's going on to someone who doesn't know how Promises work, but I'll do my best. For each of the code examples below, try copying and pasting it to your console. Feel free to play around with it!!

`Promise.resolve()` just creates a resolved Promise (optionally with a value). It's a simple way to start a promise chain:

```
var foo = Promise.resolve(1234);
foo.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result); //-> 1234
});
```

Within a `then()` function, you can return a new value. The new value is used in subsequent calls to `then()`:

```
var foo = Promise.resolve(1234);
foo.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result); //-> 1234
    return 5678;
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result); //-> 5678
    return "BLAGH";
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result); //-> BLAGH
    // do not return anything
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result); //-> undefined
});
```

If you return a new Promise, then the promise chain will wait for that promise to resolve. This is the coolest part about promises IMO. Copy this code to your console and notice how each result is printed after 1000ms. You can think of the timeouts as AJAX requests:

```
var foo = Promise.resolve(1234);
foo.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result); //-> 1234;
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(5678);
        }, 1000);
    });
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result); //-> 5678
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve("BLAGH");
        }, 1000);
    });
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result); //-> "BLAGH"
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result); //-> undefined
});
```

Comment: I really don't understand what's going on here, but it works!

Comment: Eesh - it's hard to explain. You should read about Promises as they are very powerful once you understand them. It's important to understand the `return` value from the `then` functions. I did, however, just realize that there was a bug in my original answer. I have updated the code accordingly. Make sure you are using the new code, or you are sure to have bugs!!

Comment: Yep, that'll do. I understand the jist of promises, but your solution went a bit over my head until you spelt it out clearly. Thanks again!